# lodash to filter and sort

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I'm using lodash to fiter an array, however, it is doing it case sensitive, I also can't work out how to query multiple fields.

Given this example:

```
let arr = [
  { a: 'John', b: 'Smith' },
  { a: 'Penny', b: 'Eversmith' },
  { a: 'Smithers', b: 'Jones' },
  { a: 'Jane', b: 'Doe' }
];
```

How can I filter this so that if someone queries by "Smith" I get back the following, give that Smith occurs in 3 records in both sentence and lowercase?

```
[
  { a: 'John', b: 'Smith' },
  { a: 'Penny', b: 'Eversmith' },
  { a: 'Smithers', b: 'Jones' }
]
```

Or, if it's simple to do without using lodash in js then i'm fine with that too.

Answer (score 0):

No need for Lodash for filtering or mapping anymore, not since ES5 (2009) added `filter` and `map` to `Array.prototype`.

If you know the names of the properties, just check them:

```
const result = arr.filter(({a, b}) => a.includes(searchStr) || b.includes(searchStr));
```

If not and you want to check **all** properties, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and `some` (another ES5 thing):

```
const result = arr.filter(entry => Object.values(entry).some(val => val.includes(searchStr));
```

`Object.values` is ES2017+, but easily polyfilled.

I've also used [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) there, which is ES2016 (and, again, easily polyfilled).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `filter` and `some` and make all the values to a single case to match to achieve case insensitivity

```js
let arr = [
  { a: 'John', b: 'Smith' },
  { a: 'Penny', b: 'Eversmith' },
  { a: 'Smithers', b: 'Jones' },
  { a: 'Jane', b: 'Doe' }
];

let findName = (arr,name) => arr.filter(val=>{
  return Object.values(val).some(v=> v.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()))
})

console.log(findName(arr,'Smith'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With **lodash** the solution does not look that different than with **ES6**:

```js
let arr = [ { a: 'John', b: 'Smith' }, { a: 'Penny', b: 'Eversmith' }, { a: 'Smithers', b: 'Jones' }, { a: 'Jane', b: 'Doe' } ];

let search = (a, s) => 
  _.filter(a, x => _(x).values().some(y => _.includes(_.toLower(y), _.toLower(s)))) 

console.log(search(arr, 'Smith'))
console.log(search(arr, 'doe'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With **ES6** this  would be somewhat shorter:

```js
let arr = [ { a: 'John', b: 'Smith' }, { a: 'Penny', b: 'Eversmith' }, { a: 'Smithers', b: 'Jones' }, { a: 'Jane', b: 'Doe' } ];

let search = (a, s) => a.filter(x => 
  Object.values(x).some(y => y.toLowerCase().includes(s.toLowerCase())))

console.log(search(arr, 'Smith'))
console.log(search(arr, 'doe'))
```